# Cannot make cProfile work in IPython

Tags: python, profiling, profiler, ipython

I'm missing something very basic.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.N = 100
        pass

    def f(self, param):
        print 'C.f -- param'
        for k in xrange(param):
            for i in xrange(self.N):
                for j in xrange(self.N):
                    a = float(i)/(1+float(j)) + float(i/self.N) ** float(j/self.N)

import cProfile

c = C()
cProfile.run('c.f(3)')
```

When I run the above code in IPython, I get:

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE** the exact paste of my session is here: http://pastebin.com/f3e1b9946

**UPDATE** I didn't mention that the problem occurs in IPython, which (at it turns out) is the source of the problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While inside IPython, you can use the [%prun magic function](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=prun#magic-prun):

```
In [9]: %prun c.f(3)
C.f -- param
         3 function calls in 0.066 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.066    0.066    0.066    0.066 <string>:6(f)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.066    0.066 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! I didn't know about %prun :)

Comment: Dead link for '%prun magic function', and I haven't found what it should be updated to.

Comment: @retracile: Thanks for the heads-up. Link fixed.

Comment: N.B. For anyone reading this now, the link's changed again: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html#IPython.core.magic.Magic.magic_prun

Comment: Now the link is: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.prun

Comment: @unutbu np... the "stable" in the name is a bit of a misnomer :)

Answer (score 16):

Not the original poster's problem, but you can also get this same error if you are invoking cProfile.run() in something other than the __main__ namespace (from within a function or an import). In that case you need to use the following instead of the run() method:

```
cProfile.runctx("your code", globals(), locals())
```

Comment: Ah! Winner, I couldn’t believe there wasn’t way to profile from the shell without editing my code.

Comment: The link for the post is broken, I did not find an equivalent URL it's possibly been deleted.

Comment: @Dudelstein You are unfortunately right. I've deleted the reference to the post.

Answer (score 3):

Although IPython is very handy, there is a lot of rare cases when it breaks working code or masks errors. So it's useful to try code in standard interpreter when you get such mystical errors.